# Format Javascript DateTime as date(‘ymdHis’) in php

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I am moving part of the php code to frontend javascript in my web application.
I need to format the current datetime as `date(‘ymdHis’)` in javascript.

I tried using javascript's `toLocaleDateString` as such:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString("ko-KR", { year: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second: "2-digit"}).replace(/\D/g,'');
```

This solves my current problem, but I used "ko-KR" locale to make the year-month-day order. If the implementation changes a little, I will have a hard time on this.

I want to know is there any javascript library for properly managing this task? Like, if next time it's `date(‘mydHis’)`, I don't have to find a locale that follows this order.

 I looked through moment.js, but it seems it's not really for numeric output as such (I didn't look into it in depth, sorry if this is wrong).

Any help would be much appreciated.

I found this while more searching, it might be helpful:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat from 
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

(Sorry I am quite new to StackOverflow, will keep in mind to use the edit next time.)

Comment: use javascript date function to first convert the coming string into proper date and then you can change it's format to desired way

Comment: you must consider using momentjs for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably don't need a library for this.

With this code you can mix and match your date/time elements as you wish:

```js
let date = new Date(2019,4,10,15,30,20) //10 May 2019, 3:30:20 PM
let dateStr = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {day:"2-digit", month:"2-digit", year:"2-digit"}) // 10/05/19

let arr = dateStr.split("/")// [ '10', '05', '19' ]
let d = arr[0]; //e.g. 10 
let m = arr[1]; //e.g. 5 
let y = arr[2]; //e.g. 19

let timeStr = date.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", {hour12:false, hour:"2-digit",minute:"2-digit", second:"2-digit"}) //
let arr2 = timeStr.split(":") // 15:30:20
let H = arr2[0]; //e.g. 15
let i = arr2[1]; //e.g. 30
let s = arr2[2]; //e.g. 20

let ymdHms = y + m + d + H + i + s;

console.log(ymdHms); //190510153020
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add  `hour12: false` in your options

```
    const opt = {
      year: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit",
      hour12: false,
      hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second: "2-digit"
    }

    new Date().toLocaleDateString("ko-KR", opt).replace(/\D/g, '');
```

but in a simple Way without Library :

```js
function form_ymdHis(xDate) {
  return xDate.getFullYear().toString(10).substring(2)
      + (xDate.getMonth()+1).toString(10).padStart(2,'0')
      + xDate.getDate().toString(10).padStart(2,'0')
      + xDate.getHours().toString(10).padStart(2,'0')
      + xDate.getMinutes().toString(10).padStart(2,'0')  
      + xDate.getSeconds().toString(10).padStart(2,'0')
}


console.log ( form_ymdHis(new Date() ))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js to format your current date.

var date = moment({your date}).toDate().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

also you can use [MOMENT](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

which is very easy to implement.